# Manhwa where mc joins phoenix guild

Tags: story-identification, manga

I remember reading a manhwa two years ago. typical hunter manhwa with gates and stuff. The only thing that really stood out was that MC made an alliance/ contract/ joined the "phoenix guild" which was known for being scummy or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might it be *[Kill the Hero](https://myanimelist.net/manga/146979/Kill_the_Hero)*?

> After he's killed by the righteous leader of his own guild, Woojin gets a chance to start over. This time he's not interested in saving the world from monsters—he's got his sights set on revenge! His high-level kills quickly garner him notoriety among the game plebs, while boosting his stats as he masterminds his way closer to the top. But there's something no one can figure out: whose side he's playing for. Now that he knows how to play to win, Woojin will stop at nothing to destroy the hero!

The guild Woojin joins is the Phoenix Guild.

Found with a search for `manhwa "phoenix guild"`